# PyCharm couldn't find "utcnow" in "datetime" (Discord.py, Python 3.8)

Tags: python, datetime, discord.py

I found this reminder command (on Stackoverflow) and I corrected some bits to go according to my cog. So there is this bit in the code which is `utcnow` and PyCharm can't find it in `datetime`

Code

```
@commands.command(case_insensitive=True, aliases=["remind", "remindme", "remind_me"])
    @commands.bot_has_permissions(attach_files=True, embed_links=True)
    async def reminder(self, ctx, time, *, reminder, counter):
        print(time)
        print(reminder)
        user = ctx.message.author
        embed = discord.Embed(color=0x55a7f7, timestamp=datetime.utcnow())
        embed.set_footer(
            text="If you have any questions, suggestions or bug reports, please join our support Discord Server: link hidden",
            icon_url=f"{self.client.user.avatar_url}")
        seconds = 0
        if reminder is None:
            embed.add_field(name='Warning',
                            value='Please specify what do you want me to remind you about.')  # Error message
        if time.lower().endswith("d"):
            seconds += int(time[:-1]) * 60 * 60 * 24
            counter = f"{seconds // 60 // 60 // 24} days"
        if time.lower().endswith("h"):
            seconds += int(time[:-1]) * 60 * 60
            counter = f"{seconds // 60 // 60} hours"
        elif time.lower().endswith("m"):
            seconds += int(time[:-1]) * 60
            counter = f"{seconds // 60} minutes"
        elif time.lower().endswith("s"):
            seconds += int(time[:-1])
            counter = f"{seconds} seconds"
        if seconds == 0:
            embed.add_field(name='Warning',
                            value='Please specify a proper duration, send `reminder_help` for more information.')
        elif seconds < 300:
            embed.add_field(name='Warning',
                            value='You have specified a too short duration!\nMinimum duration is 5 minutes.')
        elif seconds > 7776000:
            embed.add_field(name='Warning',
                            value='You have specified a too long duration!\nMaximum duration is 90 days.')
        else:
            await ctx.send(f"Alright, I will remind you about {reminder} in {counter}.")
            await asyncio.sleep(seconds)
            await ctx.send(f"Hi, you asked me to remind you about {reminder} {counter} ago.")
            return
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure you are importing the datetime library:

```
import datetime
```

Depending on your import, the correct call to the datetime functions will be something like this:

```
datetime.datetime.utcnow()
```

This happens because you are actually importing a file like `datetime.py` and within it exists the class you want to use, called `datetime`.

For some reference, the whole call explained:

- datetime - tells python to select in the datetime module
- datetime - tells python to select the class datatime in that module
- utcnow - tells python to select the method utcnow in that class
- () - execute that module.

Comment: Wow, thanks. But why do we have to add another `datetime` to the code? Why doesn't Python allow just one `datetime`?

Comment: @235baron Edited my comment with an exaplanation to why this happens.